# Fastest way to know in which section of line is a point

Tags: python, performance, shapely, code-review

I have a line and a point. I want to locate where is this point in the line according to imaginary sections I make (any way I want). The output should be in which number of section is the point (sections of the line are made in an ordered way)

I tried this as an example:

```
import shapely.geometry as spg
import shapely.ops as spo

line = spg.LineString([(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)])

# WAY TO SECTION I COME UP WITH
points_coord = []
number_sections = 4
for i in range(0,number_sections):
    point = line.interpolate(i+1)
    points_coord.extend(point.coords[:])
points = spg.MultiPoint(points_coord)

#SECTION OF LINE
geom = spo.split(line,points)

# FIND POINT IN LINE SECTIONS
p = spg.Point(0.5,0)
for index,sec_line in enumerate(geom):
    if (sec_line.intersects(new_p)):
        print("it is in section number:",index)
```

Is there any other way to do this faster?

Maybe I am not aware of a better shapely function that does exactly this or a more compact and faster way in basic python to loop all lines, etc.

I need to do this with a lot of points in real time and I need to be as fast as possible.

Comment: If you use float coordinates your code won't work there will be no intersection between the line and the point because the point won't be exactly on the line. You may create a circle from the point with a radius of the tolerance. I don't know why you write the first loop, you should use line.coordinates to get the coordinates of vertexes of the line.

Comment: I tested with some other lines and I realised the problem you said with float coordinates (specially using `split`), but I have made a workaround. The decision to interpolate the points to section the line is in case that I need the point between the vertexes, but it is true that in this case is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster way with tolerance (see my comment):

```
import shapely.geometry as spg
import shapely.ops as spo

line = spg.LineString([(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)])

# create circle for intersection
tolerance = 0.1
c = spg.Point(0.5,0).buffer(tolerance)
# get points of linestring
points = line.coords
for index in range(len(points)-1):
    l = spg.LineString(points[index:index+2])
    if (l.intersects(c)):
        print("it is in section number:",index)
        break
```

This code eliminate your first loop to make line segments using *LineString.coords*. The *break* in the loop exit looping after the first intersecting line segment found. This code approximately five times faster then yours.

Comment: Thx, really useful, specially the break statement after locating the intersection.